# delete created inputs after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a code where I can add inputs, with `@click="addInput()"` .

Now I'm trying do delete these inputs as well with `@click="deleteInput()`. I've tried to do this with `this.inputs.splice(index, 1)` - but when I try this only my last input will be deleted.. but I don't know why..

How can I solve that, that my specific Input which I want to delete will be deleted?

**The additional code in my inputs at `addInput` -> `name` is from child element**

Thanks for helping me out!

my template:

```
<template>
  <div >
    <div class="mt-2" v-for="(id, index) in inputs" :key="index">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <b-button-group class="col-md-12">
          <b-button class="col-md-8" v-b-toggle="toggleElementInChildVue" variant="danger"></b-button>
          <b-button @click="deleteInput(index)" class="col-md-4" variant="danger">Delete this!</b-button>
        </b-button-group>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <b-button @click="addInput()">Add Input</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

my script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',

  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{
        name: "",
      }],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    deleteInput(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1)
    },
  
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({
        name: "",
      })
    },
  },  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your delete method works, check snippet pls:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{
        name: "aa",
      }],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    deleteInput(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1)
    },
  
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({
        name: "bb",
      })
    },
  },  
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <div >
    <div class="mt-2" v-for="(name, index) in inputs" :key="index">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <b-button-group class="col-md-12">
          <b-button class="col-md-8"  variant="danger">{{name}}</b-button>
          <b-button @click="deleteInput(index)" class="col-md-4" variant="danger">Delete this!</b-button>
        </b-button-group>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <b-button @click="addInput()">Add Input</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, get following: ```Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'```..

Comment: Ah, sorry mate my bad, check my updated answer your method works :)

Comment: Hi, what have you changed? I can't figure it out.. :( - for me it's the same like in my question.. :) and this does not work..

Comment: I didn't change anything, just putted som values in item name, so you can see that you delete the right one, try snippet pls

Comment: yes! now after getting your confirmation I've have deteced my mistake.. - I have values in my v-b-toggle and these are not changing.. thanks for taking, and wasting (I'm sorry), your time :)